# JSLint Bad option 'window:true'

Tags: javascript, jslint, lint

I am currently configuring **[JS Lint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ajhyndman.jslint)** for **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** and I keep on getting this strange warning telling me that the global window setting is a "bad option" like so:

[image]

My JSLint comment is as follows:

### `/*global window: true */`

No space between the * and g , and yet it shows me the warning anyways.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of globals is just a list. There's no `: true` involved.

```
/*global window*/
```

Comment: Now we wait 7 minutes to click on the tick.